# Custom Numberpicker in listview

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom numberpicker in my listview. I add quantity in numberpicker for first item in my list but when I scroll through the list then without adding the same quantity appears in random items numberpicker. How to solve that?

if you have any suggestion plz give me.

for image

http://ashutoshkumarojha.wordpress.com/2013/05/10/numberpicker-in-listview/

Comment: Can you give me adapter class code so that i am able to answer.

Comment: i have not any adapter class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because of **view recycling** .. you should use view holder and check for position before setting the quantity..

check http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/